# 640px or 1080px Width for Mobile Theme Design?

Tags: mobile, themes, width

I'm struggling to understand what width size to design my mobile theme in. A previous design company drafted me an app design and it was all produced using a 640px wide template, this is the ideal size I want to create my new theme in because it works well with the outline icons I want to use which are 48px and this is the right size for the Navigation Bar.

However the coder who will be putting the mobile theme together has suggested I produce the theme at a width of 1080px which is almost double the width size I am currently using and I will not be able to size up the icons to fit this size.

I'd really appreciate some advice on this, I've read that it's also an option to create multiple sizes which automatically convert depending on which device is used.

Comment: Perhaps this might be useful: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Comment: It's for a mobile version of our website and mostly directed for people's mobile phones. I hadn't taken landscape into consideration, as you can tell this is the first time I've designed a mobile version. The issue with designing in varied sizes is the icons, is it recommended to do it all in Illustrator and use vector icons so they can be sizes down when on smaller screens?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what kind of application are you talking about. If it is a website, then 320-480 is the ideal for portrait, around 640 for landscape.
If it is a native application, then you might want to use 1080p, because modern mobile phones support full HD apps. Therefore it will look much nicer & crisper.

Also you want to think about if its going to be responsive ( adapting to screen width ) or not.